# How to add the arguments with each function calling

Tags: cmake, build

I am trying here to add the arguments given by the user with every function calling. But currently instead of adding it to the old variable it always overwrites the variable.

In `CMakeLists.txt` file, when I am calling function `mic_set_classes` twice. It should append the variable and give the final output as previous call inputs (`swsrc pjtsrc`) and the new call inputs (`pjthdr`). But currently the output is only pjthdr.

```
mic_set_classes(CLASS_TYPE src CLASS_LIST swsrc pjtsrc)

mic_set_classes(CLASS_TYPE hdr CLASS_LIST pjthdr)
```

for the reference: mic_set_classes function

```
# argument parsing
set(oneValueArgs CLASS_TYPE)
set(multiValueArgs CLASS_LIST)
cmake_parse_arguments(MIC_SET_CLASSES "" "${oneValueArgs}" "${multiValueArgs}" ${ARGN})
```

The final output is the comma separated arguments in this case : `pjthdr`, . Only this is obtained. Instead of the above, how to print something like this:
`swsrc, pjtsrc, pjthdr`. All the previous arguments and the current arguments given to the function. Also, I am using:

`set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY GLOBAL_ALL_CLASS ${all_list_types})`
and this  ${all_list_types}, I am calling in other function using
`get_property(class_list GLOBAL PROPERTY GLOBAL_ALL_CLASS)`.

```
function(mic_set_classes)
    
    set(oneValueArgs CLASS_TYPE)
    set(multiValueArgs CLASS_LIST)
    cmake_parse_arguments(MIC_SET_CLASSES "" "${oneValueArgs}" "${multiValueArgs}" ${ARGN})

# Comma separation
list(LENGTH MIC_SET_CLASSES_CLASS_LIST LENGTH_OF_CLASS_LIST)
MATH(EXPR VAR "${LENGTH_OF_CLASS_LIST}-1")
foreach(Z RANGE 0 ${VAR} )
        set(all_list_types "")
        foreach(A IN LISTS MIC_SET_CLASSES_CLASS_LIST)
            string(APPEND all_list_types "${A},") 
        endforeach()  
endforeach()

set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY GLOBAL_ALL_CLASS ${all_list_types})

endfunction()

# Function where swsrc, pjtsrc, pjthdr has to be used
function(mic_parse_project)

get_property(class_list GLOBAL PROPERTY GLOBAL_ALL_CLASS)
execute_process(COMMAND ${MIC_PARSE_PROJECT_INVMNG} -c ${class_list})

endfunction()
```

Comment: "... and give the final output" - Which variable you are printing in a "final output"? The variables created by `cmake_parse_arguments` are **local** to the function, so their are destroyed upon function ends.

Comment: @Tsyvarev The final output is the comma separated arguments in this case : `pjthdr`, .Only this is obtained. Instead of the above, how to print something like `swsrc, pjtsrc, pjthdr`. All the previous arguments and the current arguments given to the function. Also I am using:  `set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY GLOBAL_ALL_CLASS ${all_list_types})`  and this  ${all_list_types}, I am calling in other function using `get_property(class_list GLOBAL PROPERTY GLOBAL_ALL_CLASS)`

Comment: Do not put the code into the comments. Instead, [edit] you question post and add the code into it. Note, that on Stack Overflow it is a **question post** which should contain all information needed to understand the problem. In the current form your question post is **unclear**.

Comment: Where do you call `set_property`? What is `all_list_types` variable, which value you store in the property? Please, prepare [mcve] and add it to the question post.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the errors. I have added in the question

Comment: Normally, `set_property` **assigns** to the property a specified value. That is, every call to your function `mic_set_classes` drops previous value of the property and writes new value, which is based on the function's parameters. If you want to **append** a value to the property, then use additional `APPEND` keyword: `set_property(GLOBAL APPEND PROPERTY GLOBAL_ALL_CLASS ${all_list_types})`. This is described in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_property.html).